# Position HTML element absolutely but have it's 100% width be that of the parent

Tags: html, css, position

For example I want to create a footer for the page. It should always be at the bottom, so I would use:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But I want the footer to always have a top border to mark it as such:

```
[...]
    border-style: solid;
    border-top: 1px;
    border-color: gray;
[...]
```

The problem now is that if the footer is very small, it's border will always be just it's content's width.

If I want to extend the width of the element to it's parent's width, using `width: 100%;`, it get's extended to the right to the far edge of the screen. `width: auto;` extends it only as far as needed, but I want it to be **at least** filling the parent.

What I want is it to be absolutely positioned at the bottom of it's parent, but not have the "detached" width calculation that absolute positioning has on the width value. I do not want to attach a different "max-width" value to each element depending on what parent such a width-filling footer should have.

Example html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <article>
            <section>Lorem Ipsum</section>
            <footer>
                <a href=www.example.com>Link</a>
            </footer>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example css:

```
article {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}

article footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: could you create the example?

Comment: How? I can't find any website letting me create a mock of what I want to show right now but I might just be using the worst words in google for that to find such a thing (mock, dummy, example html results are ... not what I want).

Comment: jsfiddle, plunkr, js bin to name but 3 or as part of stackoverlow, they have an option to create html and javascript page as part of question or answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this issue by setting the left offset value to 0:

```
footer {    
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You would then need to set container element that you want to position the footer in to have a position of value relative

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  container
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
 </div>
```

Comment: This just changes the problem by extending the footer the the left of the page too, but if the footer is part of a small box I want it to be aligned to that box, not to the viewport.

Comment: The change to having the parent a relative position worked. I just read the w3schools article again and saw that absolute takes the next best NON-STATIC parent into account and unless specified, everything is static. That was the problem.